# CSS class applying but not id

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a quiz, and so I would like to apply the same class but with different ids to three text inputs. However, for some reason, my class CSS is applying but my ids aren't. HTML:

```
            <form>
                <input id="0" class="textbs" type="text" >
                <input id="1" class="textbs" type="text">
                <input id="2" class="textbs" type="text">
                <input type="button" id="submmit" value="GO">
            </form>
```

CSS:

```
.textbs {
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: geneva;
    border: solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.54);
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

#0 {
    background-color: black;
}

#1 {
    display: none;
}

#2 {
    display:none;
}
```

I tried to change the #0 background-color to black to see if it identified the input id or not, and it stayed white (default), but when I added a background-color:black; line to .textbs it applied. Help please!

Comment: Seriously, don't you ever name elements starting with digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID's shouldn't start with a number , while you can still try out this:

```
[id='0'] {
 /* should work */
}

 #0 {
  /* shouldn't work */
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KjrK7/)

Comment: Although using the attribute selector (instead of the id selector) can work in this case but it can't replace the id selector. The attribute selector has the specificity much less than the id selector (which has the most specificity).

Answer (score 0):

id's cannot start with a number.

Change them to "one" "two" "three" etc. if need be.

Comment: Why do you cite `<div>` specifically?

Answer (score 0):

please give id's as identifiers which start with letters or special character '_'.
And position:"absolute" is not required.
try this.

```
<form>
                <input id="a0" class="textbs" type="text" >
                <input id="a1" class="textbs" type="text">
                <input id="a2" class="textbs" type="text">
                <input type="button" id="submmit" value="GO">
            </form>
.textbs {
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: geneva;
    border: solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.54);
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;

    margin-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

#a0{
    background-color: black;
}

#a1 {
    display: none;
}

#a2 {
    display:block;
}
```